# Xamarin Forms - Get Image to Fill width of containing Grid Column?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Having an issue with Xamarin Forms trying to ensure an image matches the width of its containing column. (Think of a simple product listing with a picture and description).

XAML code is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="formsApp.MainPage">
  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Orientation="Vertical"
                   Spacing="15" >
        <Grid x:Name="testGrid"  VerticalOptions="Center">
        </Grid>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

C# code behind is:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
        testGrid.Padding = new Thickness(10D);
        testGrid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
        testGrid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();

        testGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        testGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) });

        for (int MyCount = 0; MyCount < 20; MyCount++)
        {
            testGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testGrid.RowDefinitions.Count(); i++)
        {
            StackLayout st = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, IsClippedToBounds = true };

            st.Children.Add(new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nYhPnY2I-e9rpqnid9u9aAODz4C04OycEGxqHG5vxFnA35OGmLMrrUmhM9eaHKJ7liB-=w300")),
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
            });

            testGrid.Children.Add(st, 0, i);

            testGrid.Children.Add(new Label
                {
                    Text = "Row" + i + " description.... fdsfsdf sdf sdfsd fsdf sdf sdf sdfsd fsd fsdf sdf sd fsd fsdf "
            }, 1, i);

        }

    }
```

I have applied various options such as wrapping the image in a Stack layout (with options on stack layout) and also adding AspectFit and EndAndExpand to the image but it is never 100% correct.[Resultant view from a 5" KitKat Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heDKV.png)

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is the `EndAndExpand` horizontal option. As far as I have understood, the `...AndExpand` *expand* the respective views if the content would not fit otherwise. Furthermore you've set the column widths of the grid to `*` and `3*`which would mean, that the first column would take a fourth of the grid width, hence there is no space to expand.

There are multiple possible solutions to this issue - depending on how you want the result to look. You could go for `Auto` and `*` regarding the columns

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

or you could make the image use only the available space

```
st.Children.Add(new Image
{
    Source = "...",
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
});
```

Both options should solve your problem.

**But**, please note, that you could even do better. Instead of using a grid, you could use a `ListView`. With `ListView`s you can use the power of data binding for your cells. You would not have to clutter your code with all that view-building code, but could declare everything in neat XAML.

Comment: Thanks for this. I went for the second option which did indeed fix the issue. However I have noticed something else:

If the original image was far too big for the space then row height is expanded to that original size (width is fine), even though the actual resultant image sits nicely at the top fits in correctly. I have this mass of space at the bottom?